# Custom sort in domaincollectionview

Tags: wcf-ria-services, icollectionview

I'm using a DCV as a property in the View Model.
Everything works fine but what about custom sort?
Say I have a string property in my model which should be sorted alphanumerically.
How can I achieve such thing?

UPD:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
///...
public SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

xaml:

```
<data:DataTextColumn Binding={binding path=SomeProperty}, canusersort=true />
```

When sorting within the datagrid, the property gets sorted with disregard to alphanumeric order, i.e. in a regular string way. I'd like to apply my custom sort, e.g. by introducing my own IComparer. No API is available at least as I know of it.
Any clues?

Comment: Add some code (model or viewmodel class) to clarify what you mean!

Comment: Added model and xaml. Basically I'm trying to override the basic sort provided by String type with a custom one. The entities are sorted perfectly at the server-side but it seems as though they are re-sorted at the client side according to default string CompareTo method. Is there any possbility to cancel/override such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The DomainCollectioView has special collection:

> SortDescriptions

You could add next code in Your ViewModel:

```
DCV.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SomeProperty ", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```